# Encrypting Data with RSA in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, cryptography, rsa

I have a `DER` file with `sha1RSA` as the `Signature Algorithm`. I have to encrypt some data using it.

Can anyone tell me how do I load the `DER` file and use the `RSA` public key in it to encrypt my data in .NET?

Comment: You shouldn't be encrypting data with an asymmetric algorithm like RSA.

Comment: It was never meant to encrypt larger chunks of data - too slow, vulnerable to attacks aiming at this etc. RSA encryption should only be used to wrap symmetric cipher keys, and even that should probably always be replaced by doing TLS right away. It depends on whether you want to actually transport the data from A to B (always use TLS there), otherwise if you really want to encrypt it (let's say to store it in the DB or on disk), then you should use symmetric encryption algorithms instead of RSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DER or Distinguished Encoding Rules is a method for encoding a data object, such as an X.509 certificate, to be digitally signed or to have its signature verified.

The X.509 certificate only contains the public key.  You need the private key to decrypt!

Typically private keys are exchanged in .PFX files, which are password protected.

-- EDIT --

Sorry I misread your question.  Yes, you can encrypt with the public key of X.509 certificate. You can load the .der by using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import method.

Then convert the public and encrypt, something like:

```
rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider) certificate.PublicKey.Key;
encryptedText = rsa.Encrypt(msg, true);
```

Comment: PFX files _can_ be password protected.

Comment: @Henk, you are technically correct.  But all private keys SHOULD be password protected.

Comment: What do you mean by verifying?  You can only encrypt or decrypt.  To decrypt you need the private key which you do not have.

Comment: And how do I convert encryptedText to string again?

Comment: You must decrypt with the private key.  Use the RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt method.

Comment: You getting off topic for this question; better to open another one.  However, you look at Convert.ToBase64String() for conversion.

Comment: DER encoding rules is an encoding of ASN.1 defined structures, which **may** consist of data to be signed/encrypted (etc.). Private keys are normally not exchanged at all, pfx is normally used for **storage**, not exchange.